# Listing Chapter/Section/Subsection numbers with the preview

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters, book-design, navigation

After compiling all the content of the book, I use Adobe reader to preview the content. Note that the legend that I use to navigate through the book (the listing on the left (usually) with the option '+' on which one clicks, and it offers the content) only contains the Chapter/Section/Subsection names. How could I change this to include the numbering, i.e, such that the legend contains, e.g., '3 Chapter name' with '+' sign, and it opens to, e.g. '3.1 Section name'...
I hope you understand what I'm asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `bookmarksnumbered` option for `hyperref` or the `numbered` option for `bookmark`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test section}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add option `bookmarksnumbered` to the `hyperref` call (or use `\hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered}`)